# What does `!:-` do?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian, sh

I am very new to bash scripting and in Ubuntu\Debian package system.

Today I am studying the content of this preinst file that the script executes before that package is unpacked from its Debian archive (.deb) file.

My fist doubt is about a line containing this:

`!:-`

Probably it is a stupid question but, using Google, I can't find an answer.

Comment: Please post more code in context of where it is used.

Comment: Do you mean `${!:-}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the last command without the last argument (bash)

```
/usr/sbin/ab2 -f TLS1 -S -n 1000 -c 100 -t 2 http://www.google.com/
```

then

```
!:- http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

is the same as

```
/usr/sbin/ab2 -f TLS1 -S -n 1000 -c 100 -t 2 http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: `!:-` is one of the so called *history interaction commands*. Check the manual to learn all that goodies: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html